# mktime() for non-local timezone

Tags: c, mktime, ctime

In C the function mktime() returns the epoch time according to the local timezone (the input struct is locally formatted).

The function timegm() returns the epoch time according to the UTC time (the input struct is formatted based off of UTC time).

The function localtime_r () takes in an epoch time and returns a local timezone formatted struct.

The function gmtime_r () takes in an epoch time and returns a UTC formatted struct.

I need to find out if a non-local timezone is currently daylight savings time or not, which would work with the localtime_r() function if it were local, but what if it were not local?

The gmtime_r() function always sets the tm_isdst field to zero, which won't work here.

Maybe there's some other function I am not aware of.  Not sure.

Comment: Set the `TZ` environment variable and then call the function that operates in the local timezone.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7107036/5128826

Comment: "Set the TZ environment variable and then call the function that operates in the local timezone."

Won't this set the timezone systemwide?  Or only for the application environment?

Comment: No, changing a process's env var will only change the process's copy of the env var. (It will also change the value inherited by any later-created children of that process.) But it could cause problems if you have a multi-threaded application. You'll need to take steps to protect yourself in such a situation.

Comment: Notes `.tm_isdst` is positive when a `struct tm` is using _daylight time_.  That usually is 1, but could be some other positive value.  Daylight time _almost always_ means 1 hour shift from standard time.  Counter example [Lord Howe Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Howe_Island).

Comment: BostonBSD, It would be insightful to know _why_ you want to know "find out if a non-local timezone is currently daylight savings time or not" as the higher level problem might be easier to solve than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to find out if a non-local timezone is currently daylight savings time or not

1. Get the current time as a `time_t` from `time`.
2. Set env var `TZ` to the target time zone using `putenv`.
3. Call `tzset`. (I don't know if this is required, but there's surely no harm in calling it.)
4. Use `localtime` to convert the `time_t` into a `struct tm` according to the (modified) local time zone.
5. Check the `tm_isdst` field of that `struct tm`.

Comment: An example of setting the TZ env variable can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=functions-tzset-set-time-zone)

Answer (score 3):

If you (a) don't want to muck around with a global environment variable and (b) have the "NetBSD inspired" time functions available to you, there's an additional possibility: `mktime_z()` and `localtime_rz()`, which let you explicitly specify the zone you want to use.  So you're not limited to your default local zone, or UTC.

Here's an example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    timezone_t tzp = tzalloc(argv[1]);
    if(tzp == NULL) return 1;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm;
    struct tm *tmp = localtime_rz(tzp, &now, &tm);
    char tmpbuf[20];
    strftime(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf), "%H:%M:%S", tmp);
    printf("right now in zone %s is %s\n", argv[1], tmpbuf);

    tm.tm_year = 1976 - 1900;
    tm.tm_mon = 7 - 1;
    tm.tm_mday = 4;
    tm.tm_hour = 12;
    tm.tm_min = tm.tm_sec = 0;
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;

    time_t t = mktime_z(tzp, &tm);

    printf("in zone %s, %d-%02d-%02d %d:%02d was %ld\n", argv[1],
        1900+tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon+1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, t);
}
```

When I invoke `tzt America/New_York` I see

```
right now in zone America/New_York is 11:58:23
in zone America/New_York, 1976-07-04 12:00 was 205344000
```

and when I invoke `tzt America/Los_Angeles` I see

```
right now in zone America/Los_Angeles is 08:58:49
in zone America/Los_Angeles, 1976-07-04 12:00 was 205354800
```

Now, with that said, two further comments, tied to my opening "if"s:

a. If you don't want to muck around with a global environment variable, I don't blame you one tiny bit.  I positively **hate** mucking around with global variables (let alone environment variables) to affect how a function like `mktime` or `localtime` behaves.  Unfortunately, however, this is the recommended way, in C, in this situation — see this question's other answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960679/mktime-for-non-local-timezone/71960774#71960774), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960679/mktime-for-non-local-timezone/71970632#71970632) for details.

b. Chances are unfortunately quite good that you *don't*, in fact, "have the NetBSD inspired time functions available to you".  They're nonstandard and not even very popular.  I was able to compile the test program above only because I had a copy of the [IANA tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and its code handy, which includes those functions *if* you also define `NETBSD_INSPIRED`.  (That's why I broke the rules and didn't show a complete example, with all `#include` lines, since mine were weird and idiosyncratic.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I wrote a decade ago that does what [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) suggests in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960774/15168):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void time_convert(time_t t0, char const *tz_value)
{
    char old_tz[64] = "-none-";
    char *tz = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz != 0)
        strcpy(old_tz, tz);
    setenv("TZ", tz_value, 1);
    tzset();
    char new_tz[64];
    strcpy(new_tz, getenv("TZ"));
    char buffer[64];
    struct tm *lt = localtime(&t0);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", lt);
    if (strcmp(old_tz, "-none-") == 0)
        unsetenv("TZ");
    else
        setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1);
    tzset();
    printf("%lld = %s (TZ=%s, DST = %d)\n",
           (long long)t0, buffer, new_tz, lt->tm_isdst);
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t t0 = time(0);
    char *tz = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz != 0)
        time_convert(t0, tz);
    time_convert(t0, "UTC0");
    time_convert(t0, "IST-5:30");
    time_convert(t0, "EST5");
    time_convert(t0, "EST5EDT");
    time_convert(t0, "PST8");
    time_convert(t0, "PST8PDT");
}
```

The output I get is:

```
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 17:03:53 (TZ=UTC0, DST = 0)
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 22:33:53 (TZ=IST-5:30, DST = 0)
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 12:03:53 (TZ=EST5, DST = 0)
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 13:03:53 (TZ=EST5EDT, DST = 1)
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 09:03:53 (TZ=PST8, DST = 0)
1650647033 = 2022-04-22 10:03:53 (TZ=PST8PDT, DST = 1)
```

Note that some of the time zones are specified without a daylight saving time, and the code reports `DST = 0` for those zones.

Be wary of changing the time zone like this in multi-threaded applications.  And be cautious about resetting the environment in case you `fork()` and `exec()` other programs with an unexpected value for the TZ environment variable.

*Note:* I've modified the code to:

- Use `long long` instead of `long` for printing the `time_t` value.  One of the annoying things is that there is no standard format string for printing the `time_t` type as an integer (indeed, the C standard doesn't even guarantee that the type is an integer, but it actually is on most systems, and POSIX requires it to be an integer type — see [`<sys/types.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)).  This change should allow 32-bit systems to work in 2038. That assumes that `time_t` is a 64-bit value even though it is a 32-bit system; if the system still uses a 32-bit `time_t`, it is terminally broken when `time_t` wraps around to -2<sup>31</sup> — but that shouldn't still be my problem then.
- Print `lt->tm_isdst` which is the information wanted in the question.

Comment: This is very similar to the code I wrote after the previous answer, thank you for this example.

Comment: Good points, @chux.  I'm glad that ikegami's answer has been re-accepted.  I've updated my code.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could accept two answers, I reinstated it because I had selected it first, but the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: You can only accept one answer, @BostonBSD.  I'm glad you chose ikegami's answer.  Steve Summit has some interesting points too.  The C library time handling code is a mess, but fixing it is messier still.  Having to mess with environment variables to get a sane answer is antithetical to modern coding styles.

Comment: @BostonBSD "if I need to know if NYC is currently on DST or STD time?"  --> Certainly   `lt->tm_isdst` satisfies that.

Comment: What gets printed depends a bit on your system.  I showed the output from a Mac running macOS Big Sur 11.6.5, but I got similar output a decade ago too (also on Macs).  What you get on other systems depends on the vagaries of that system's C library.  Yes, if you run this program during the winter, if you use `TZ=EST5DST`, it should report `DST = 0`.  You might be able to use `America/New_York` as another name for that time zone.  The whole area is fraught!  IANA TZ is good if you're interested (and noisy if you're not).

Comment: @BostonBSD A lot here depends on how perfect and robust you need this solution to be.  The question of "Is location X on DST at time Y?" is an almost impossible one to answer perfectly and in general.  It's already hard, and it's getting worse: numerous locations are considering switching to "permanent DST", but it's not obvious what that means: maybe you're always on DST, or maybe daylight time is the new standard time, so you're always on standard time, never on daylight time.

Comment: On FreeBSD 13.0 "America/New_York" does work as a TZ value with the correct tm_isdst value.  This might be safer than using the EST5DST formats which imply a static difference from UTC.

Comment: @BostonBSD Yes, the reported `.tm_isdst` reflects that timezone's daylight time setting for that timestamp.  Various answer, like this one, support that.

Comment: But, yes, looking at `tm_isdst` is probably the only sane way of doing this.  (Do *not* look at time zone name strings and try to parse them yourself — you're guaranteed to get into trouble that way.)

Comment: By the way, unless you're using Windows, you *are* using the IANA tz database.  My answer refers to some reference code that comes along with that database, and you're probably not using that code, but whatever system and whatever `mktime`/`localtime` implementation you're using, it's probably running on the IANA tz data underneath.  It's used by Unix, Linux, MacOS, Android, and afaik all phones.

Comment: JonathanLeffler, "no standard format string for printing the time_t type as an integer", sadly true no simple modifier way.  `printf("%.0Lf\n", truncl(some_time_t_value));` should do the trick for many cases.